# Why is not the my listeners hit here in this Firestore set

Tags: android, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I have this strange thing where `OnSuccessListener` or `OnFailureListener` stopped being called. Everything works ok but when I turn of mobile data and Wifi non of the `OnSuccessListener` or `OnFailureListener` is being called.

If I put a breakpoints on the below code `ref.set(update).....` the breakpoints are indeed hit but non of the `OnSuccessListener` or `OnFailureListener` fires

```
 Map<String, String> update = new HashMap<>();
    update.put(ByteData.DATA, data);
    DocumentReference ref = firestore
            .collection(DEVICE_DATA)
            .document(FirestoreManager.getInstance().getUserId())
            .collection(DEVICE_DATA_STREAM)
            .document(batteryEntity.getEntityId());
    ref.set(update).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
             // do some stuff
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
             // do some stuff
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> when I turn of mobile data and Wifi [neither] the `OnSuccessListener` or `OnFailureListener` is being called

That is the expected behavior. The completion listeners are only called once the data has been written on (or rejected by) the server.

The listener doesn't fire for local write operation. If the local write operation were to fail, the client will raise a regular exception.

Comment: But I cant add like 'OnExceptionListener' like I added the 'OnSuccessListener'. Can you elaborate? I want to detect when the write cant be done because of no Internet. How would I do that?

Comment: The Firestore client is designed to continue functioning fine without an internet connection. So writing to the database without an internet connection is (by design) not raised as an error condition. You can build a time-out mechanism for the completion listeners, or detect on your own whether there is an internet connection. I'd also recommend watching the latest episode in [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](firestore.video), which covers [offline behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDvdAFP6OhQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=10&t=1s).

Comment: Thanks, can you give link example on the "time-out mechanism for the completion listeners,"

Comment: There is nothing built in for that. So you'll have to build it yourself with something like a `Timer`. A quick [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+time+out+mechanism) shows many promising links to get started with.

Comment: Thanks puff but there has to be a way to easily know when the write/set is not done to the Firestore cloud db, (and by so indicating an offline write no internet write)

Comment: As said: the Firestore client doesn't consider lack of internet connection a fault condition, since it handles this condition gracefully by synchronizing once the connection is restored. The only type of write operation that requires an internet connection is a transaction.

Comment: The best way to handle connectivity is to display the actual status of the write to your user, which you can do with a completion listener, or by observing the same document and checking its metadata to see if it has pending writes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot Puff I removed the 'OnSuccessListener' and 'OnFailureListener' and added on 
 'addOnCompleteListener' trying to see when 'task.isSuccessful()' or not. This does not work I think I will go with a Transaction since I really need to know if this failed. I have learn a lot Thanks

Comment: I have this Bluetooth battery (ble) that I connect to with my mobile. It pushes notifications like every 2 second. I then In my app propagate this data to Firestore so another mobile using the same app can listen to the data. I have turned of the setPersistenceEnabled(false) because it does not make sence here, but anyway my problem was that when Internet go down I must in the app show a message like "No Internet no data is sent"

Comment: I understand the use-case, as it's quite common. That's why I iterated the options in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444042/why-is-not-the-my-listeners-hit-here-in-this-firestore-set/57444098?noredirect=1#comment101364927_57444098. Detecting internet is quite common.